# Problem connecting to ubuntu server via wlan

Tags: networking, server

I'm having a strange problem...

I have a home server (ubuntu 22.04) connected via ethernet to my router. Server has many services/ports available (apache, transmission, plex, samba, ssh) but i can´t connect to it through wifi connection. If I try to connect through ethernet it will connect without problems. I have no way to connect to any service in the home server, all of them respond with timeout as if anything would block the connection.

I've tried yet:

- Disabling UFW on home server
- Disabling AV/Firewalls on client computers (2 W11 PCs & 1 OSX 10.15 laptop)
- Confirming that both WLAN and Ethernet connections are in the same subnet, same netmask, etc.

Connecting a client through ethernet gives me access to any service on the server.

What can I try next?

Thanks...

Comment: The wifi and the wired connections are 2 different networks. You would need something routing in between. Are the wire and wireless access points the same device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistery solved! The problem was my ISP's router blocking WLAN traffic to LAN. I tried switching the router with another one and services on the server were appearing again.